# Possible windows virus infection?

Tags: server, malware

Our IT team reported that a virus scan they did against an ubuntu server came back with:

> /sys/kernel/boot_params/data: Win.Trojan.Blackhole-36 FOUND

When I looked at that file I can see text like

> ^H]�^?^@^@�,1��^?^@^@�31��^?^@^@lware.Rootkit_0024-6082079-0^@�Q2��^?^@^@lware.Rootkit_0024-6082080-0^@ڭ1��^?^@^@lware.Rootkit_0024-6082081-0^@we

I have scanned the system with clamav and rkhunter and they have found nothing

My understanding is that this file only contains debugging information.

Can anyone please advise me of any other steps that I shuold be taking here?